# Augur: getShareToken returns error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string

Tags: error, augur

I use the following code:

```
        augur.api.Market.getShareToken({
            _outcome: "0x1",
            tx: { to: _market },
        }, function (error, shareToken) { 
            console.log(error, shareToken); 
        });
```

This returns:

> Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal hex string of odd length into Go struct field CallArgs.to of type common.Address
>       at parseEthereumResponse (/Users/jasperdegooijer/Documents/flux/initial-testing/augur-client/node_modules/ethrpc/src/decode-response/parse-ethereum-response.js:8:47)

This is the exact same code that's showed in the augur documentation: https://docs.augur.net/#market-call-api

I'm linking to a YesNoMarket address, maybe that's what causing the error? If so how'd I get the ShareToken addresses of a YesNoMarket? 
I also tried adding `from` to the `tx` object but this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by creating a new market and the exact same code worked like a charm..